# Редактирование в коде пропадает

Tags: wordpress

купили шаблон, если я редактирую в коде, то все, что я поменяла, а это:

- добавление классов, якорей,
- убрала кнопки со ссылками, потому что мне нужна просто кнопка.

Если я захожу утром на следующий день, то возвращается все как было изначальное, как-будто я ничего не добавляла, не редактировала.
с чем это может быть связано?

Раньше был другой шаблон, все было ок. Редактирую в коде, сохраняю и никуда ничего не испаряется.

Я не понимаю, почему так происходит. Можете кто знает, в чем проблема с этим шаблоном?

Comment: 1. [Не шаблон, а тема](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F). 2. Используйте [механизм дочерних тем](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/).

Comment: хотите сказать, что я не там редактирую?

Comment: Хочу сказать, что как минимум неправильно это делаете.

Comment: как-то странно
делаю как обычно, но в новом шаблоне возникли проблемы, которые в вопросе..

Comment: Согласен с SeVlad, может быть просто тема обновилась и внесенные данные пропали, сделайте правки в дочерней теме, если повториться разбирайтесь уже на хостинге, мб сделали откат сайта

Comment: сейчас попробую сделать в дочерней теме и посмотрю как будет завтра работать.
А откат, каждый день хотите сказать делается?) мы темболее не запрашивали

Comment: а получается нужно активировать дочернюю тему и в ее коде редактировать, верно?